# Month Sorting in Slicer/Filter (PowerBI)

Tags: sorting, filter, powerbi, slicers, monthcalendar

I created a year hierarchy to be used in a slicer/filter (as shown below)

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJSpP.jpg)

However, when i put the "Month" into the slicer, it sorts in alphabetical order instead of from Jan-Dec (as shown below)

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUZBX.jpg)

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new column in your Date table. Something like:

```
MonthNum = MONTH([Date])
```

Then select your Month column, under `Column tools` tab in the ribbon, select `Sort by column` and select the new column you just created (`MonthNum`).